# Verificar string está contido em Array PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Tenho uma função em cURL, seu retorno é uma quantidade indefinida de dados, mas, seu formato é padrão.

Retorno:

```
    array(86) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(1)
        ["data"]=>
        string(27) "retorno 1"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(2)
        ["data"]=>
        string(13) "retorno 2"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(3)
        ["data"]=>
        string(87) "retorno 3"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(4)
        ["data"]=>
        string(33) "retorno 4"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(5)
        ["data"]=>
        string(28) "retorno 5"
      }
    }
```

Preciso verificar se uma variavel está contida no valor `string` e obter o numero do array da sequencia.

Tentei desta forma:

```
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $var= 'minha_variavel';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $content; $i++)
    {
        $element = $content->string($i);
        if (preg_match("#{$var}#i", $element))
        {
            return 'OK achei';
        }
    }
```

Sem sucesso

Answer (score 4):

Se "contido" que quer dizer for "idêntico" você pode usar o `array_search`:

```
$index = array_search('Procurado', array_column($array, 'data'), true);
```

**[Teste isto.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b68525ae4267793d35d209375399c36ee8cc0cc)**

*Isso somente irá funcionar se o valor de `data` for o mesmo que o pesquisado. Considerado que uma das `data` seja `Alguma Coisa`: pesquisar por `Alguma Coisa` irá funcionar, caso seja pesquisado por `Alguma` não será achado.*

Answer (score 2):

Tens de usar [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) para saber o tamanho da array (ie: o limite do loop), e depois `$content[$i][$i]` para ires buscando o index/elemento correto:

```
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$var = 'minha_variavel';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++){
    if ($content[$i].data == $var) return 'OK achei';
    // ou no caso de procurares uma parte somente:
    if (strpos($content[$i].data, $var) !== false) return 'OK achei'; 
}
```